# IOS PDF Reader with search , annotation and bookmarks

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics, cgpdf

I'm trying to do a PDF Reader which have the following features:

1. bookmarks
2. zooming
3. highlight //annotation or just changing the background of the rect
4. search

what I'm using is vfr/Reader :
 ***https://github.com/vfr/Reader***
it have the zooming function and bookmarks

and I want to make it like LazyPDf : ***https://github.com/lazyprogram/LazyPDFKit***

which have annotation function

or make it like ***github.com/Ink/ThatPDF***
which have less annotation functions than lazypdf

and add the search from 
***github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten***

the problem is that i have been working on it for like a month and I didn't make any progress and I don't know where to start or how to merge those applications together , even though all of them uses CGPDF.

please help me to find a way to make my app or let me know if there is a better free library ,and if i need to learn anything just drop a link in a comment.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link for pdf reader.

> you can easly use the book mark,zooming,saved pdf,email,print pdf

https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Comment: Vidhi Patel I need to know how to add the search and highlight features to it as i mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iOS PDFKit:

This [reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57428675/8160252) will help you