# Highlight and Ink Annotations in PDFKit iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, annotations, ios11

I am working on a PDF Reader app in iOS 11 swift. I need to highlight text and scribble using ink annotations. I've been using iOS PDFKit framework but I can't find a sample implementation of these.

Comment: Apple doesn't offer UI to create ink or highlight annotations. There are several 3rd-party commercial solutions available to fill in the gap, like https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/migration-guides/migrating-from-apple-pdfkit/

Answer (score 3):

You can use PdfKit Annotation: (you have select some text before execute this method)

```
PDFSelection *select = [[PDFSelection alloc] initWithDocument:_pdfView.document];
[select addSelection:_pdfView.currentSelection];
NSArray *arrayByLine = _pdfView.currentSelection.selectionsByLine;
for (PDFSelection *select in arrayByLine) {
    PDFAnnotation *annotation = [[PDFAnnotation alloc] initWithBounds:[select boundsForPage:_pdfView.currentPage] forType:PDFAnnotationSubtypeHighlight withProperties:nil];
    annotation.color =[UIColor yellowColor];
    [_pdfView.currentPage addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

There is a lot of annotation you can use:

```
PDFAnnotationSubtypeUnderline
PDFAnnotationSubtypeStrikeOut
PDFAnnotationSubtypeSquare
PDFAnnotationSubtypeCircle
PDFAnnotationSubtypeHighlight
.......
```

for swift user check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57428675/8160252)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check PDFKit Framework!

In PDFDocument class you will find below method

```
open func findString(_ string: String, withOptions options: NSString.CompareOptions = []) -> [PDFSelection]
```

This method will return you array of PDFSelection, which you can assign directly to PDFView using below method of PDFView Class

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
open var highlightedSelections: [PDFSelection]?
```